# Converting text to speech

Tags: android, text, speech

I am using the following code. Its working fine except a problem that i have list of text to converted as speech. But its only converting last line as a speech. Here is my code where I am putting data in listview and trying to convert it into speech:

```
  public class TextSpeech extends ListActivity implements
  TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {
  /** Called when the activity is first created. */

 private TextToSpeech tts;

 private TextView txtText;
 private List<Message> mess;
 List<String> titless;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.speach);

 tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);


 BaseFeedParser parser = new BaseFeedParser();
 mess = parser.parse();
 titless = new ArrayList<String>(mess.size());
    speakOut();
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
 @Override
 public void onDestroy() {
 // Don't forget to shutdown tts!
 if (tts != null) {
tts.stop();
tts.shutdown();
  }
super.onDestroy();
  }


@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public void onInit(int status) {

if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {

int result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);

if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
        || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
    Log.e("TTS", "This Language is not supported");
} else {

    speakOut();
}

    } else {
Log.e("TTS", "Initilization Failed!");
    }

   }

   public void speakOut() {
     for (Message msg : mess){
 titless.add(msg.getTitle());
 tts.speak(msg.getTitle(), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
         }
     ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = 
     new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row,titless);
     this.setListAdapter(adapter);
      }
     }
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Why don't you convert the whole list into a string and then pass that to speak function. I don't know if i am understanding your requirement.

Comment: Also, you can use TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD to add one after the other

Comment: @MeenalSharma why dont you put that as an answer so the OP can accept the answer. ;-)

Comment: @MeenalSharma Can you tell me how to get hindi language as a speech

Comment: you mean you want TTS to read Hindi

Comment: yes..want hindi in place of local.US

Comment: try to use tts.setLanguage(new Locale("hi")); or tts.setLanguage(new Locale("hin"));

Comment: but does it convert text to speech in hindi??

Comment: it cannot be done http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10005867/how-to-use-hindiindian-mother-tongue-language-in-text-to-speech see this link

Comment: please suggest anything else..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had used TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH just changed it to TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD .According to your requirement you want TTS to read one by one.