# Hindi Text To Speak Issue

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I have referred [speak-with-tts-such-as-hindi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16605247/speak-with-tts-such-as-hindi)

and i have done like this:

```
extToSpeech text2speechHi;

 text2speechHi=new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
            @Override    public void onInit(int status) {
                if(status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
                    text2speechHi.setLanguage(new Locale("hin"));
                }
            }
        });



text2speechHi.speak(getResources().getString(R.string.hindi_text), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
```

But still not reading....
how to see the output ? whether change any device setting in which i run the code?? or need to install anything??

what is this `eSpeak` they have mention in that link...any other free option available?? Any one who implemented this successfully????

It is working in fine for English `text2speech.setLanguage(Locale.UK);`

Comment: not sure may be helps you http://stackoverflow.com/a/10010879/3790150

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `speak()` before initialization is done, i.e., before onInit is called, consequently `setLanguage` hasn't been called yet. Refactor your code to follow the asynchronous pattern, by e.g. moving `speak()` into the `onInit` method.

EDIT: OP says code snippet in question is not representative of the actual code. Awaiting clarification before removing or updating answer.

Comment: Actually i am calling speak() from another function. It was working fine if langauge is text2speech.setLanguage(Locale.UK); ...so i dont think its because of any pattern if i am not wrong

Comment: In that case, why are you submitting irrelevant code? Please update with your actual code.

Comment: Do you even have a Hindi TTS engine installed?

Comment: no what is tts engine?? where to install?? in my mobile??

Comment: A tts (text to speech) engine is what actually supplies sound files and transformations from text to synthesized speak. Google's engine should nowadays support Hindi, but it might be a good start to check that you have it installed and active in your device settings (under language). If that looks OK, the next logical step would be to post your actual code along with telling us what actually happens. Also perhaps read up on Android tts, it's all in the docs and their developer blog

Comment: In my device, under language &input -> Speech -> Text-to-speech output ->picoTTS this is what i have..i think picoTTS doesnt support Hindi..so what to do?

Comment: Then you install a tts that does. Should be several on Google Play. Google's own tts can be found at https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.tts